# How to use jQuery to get data inside div's

Tags: jquery, html, dom, parent-child, each

I have the following:

```
jQuery('.activity-feed .comments div > li').each(function() {
 // Refer to each piece of data here
});
```

The problem I am having, is that for each of these div's, I want to pull some data from a child of a child of a child etc etc.  How do I reference these DOM elements?  I tried:

```
jQuery(this.find(".comment-container .note .activity-event div .meta a").text());
```

But this didn't work.  I just need to strip data out into variables.  I'm sure it's simple but I haven't done anything similar before and nothing I search for quite covers it.

---

Please note, I am aware $() would be nicer than jQuery() but it won't work with the system I am manipulating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` in the `each` iteration will refer to the DOM element. If you want to use jQuery methods on that element, you need to wrap it in a jQuery object: `$(this)`:

```
jQuery(this).find(".comment-container .note .activity-event div .meta a").text();
```

> Please note, I am aware $() would be nicer than jQuery() but it won't work with the system I am manipulating.

A jQuery object is passed in to the DOMReady handler by default, so you can still use the `$` variable within the scope of that handler only. This should not interfere with any other scripts you have. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.activity-feed .comments div > li').each(function() { 
        var foo = $(this).find(".comment-container .note .activity-event div .meta a").text();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, I see where I went wrong immediately.  Thank you, will mark as correct when time is up!